# git pull --rebase taking too long , what alternate do I have?

Tags: git, github

`git pull --rebase` is taking too long , what alternate do I have ?

In our organization we have a huge repo in which many of developers are committing daily.

I wanted to rebase the code to latest before I raise a pull request.
I was about 3000 commits behind the main repo. The rebase took about 4 hours (I didn't have any merge conflicts).

I know that a `git clone` would be much faster. What alternates do I have , other than deleting my fork and freshly forking it from the main repo?

Comment: Interesting question. How often do you pull/rebase?

Comment: This time I did after a month.

Comment: Then that's your problem. You should pull changes regularly. Letting the whole thing stagnate for a month before you pull is a no-no.

Comment: @mah The stashing will only keep aside uncommitted changes. All the other commits which Ajay has done in the 30 days will have to be reapplied and that's what will take the time.

Comment: Thanks Noufal and Mah for your inputs , one more doubt , What exactly is the time taking operation here ? I only have one commit , and before rebasing I think git will roll back to the previous commit. Will it be applying the commit one by one ? In that case if I soft reset one commit back , then stash the changes and then do a pull will it  not try to pull commit by commit and execute faster ?

Comment: Git will apply your changes one by one and if only one is there, it shouldn't take too long. I can't think of why it would take 4 hours. That's huge. If you had done a `git fetch` before doing a rebase/merge, we would have been able to tell if the network was to blame.

Comment: My guess is that it's just the size of the data coming in and writing them all to disk. The `git` project has around 35k commits. That's over around 10 years. Your project is generating 1/10 of that in a single month so it must be that.

Answer (score 1):

I was not aware of 'git merge' when I had posted the question. Or rather I was much used to 'git rebase' than I was used to 'git merge'.

What 'git rebase' does is take all your commits out until it finds a common parent and then apply upstream changes(The branch that you are merging) first and then apply the changes you have in your current branch. This process takes a long time. You have to fix the conflicts each time after fixing the conflicts.

Now I use git merge whenever there is a big merge to be done. It works a lot better and faster than rebasing.

Comment: You should also make sure never to get 3000 commits behind your merge target as well, be it frequent rebasing or frequent merging (into your branch). This would've solved the problem with the long rebase as well. If you willingly sit in isolation and don't want to take in changes, then at some point you **have to**, and then all the work you've postponed just comes back, with interest.

Answer (score 0):

Note: starting with Git 2.14.x/Git 2.15 (Q3 2017), the rebase part of `git pull --rebase` will clearly display the number of patches being prepared as well as a progress indicator.

See [commit 9eaa858](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9eaa858eb90802b9b6ce8a061229faba463f4bc3), [commit 738e88a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/738e88a20cd4c73930a18c759ed6f5704e85109f) (10 Aug 2017) by [Kevin Willford (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ad7d3c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad7d3c3b391b73207fbb29da99d4f64ad0c54f00), 23 Aug 2017)</sup>

> ### `format-patch`: have progress option while generating patches
>
> When generating patches for the rebase command, if the user does
>   not realize the branch they are rebasing onto is thousands of
>   commits different, there is no progress indication after initial
>   rewinding message.
>
> The progress meter as presented in this patch assumes the thousands of
>   patches to have a fine granularity as well as assuming to require all
>   the same amount of work/time for each, such that a steady progress bar
>   is achieved.
>
> This patch allows a progress option to be passed to format-patch
>   so that the user can be informed the progress of generating the
>   patch.

So next time, you know right away that the rebase will take time.

Note also that it will take way more time if done on Windows through msys2 than on Linux.

An alternative would be to create a `tmp` branch, then reset your current branch to the `origin` remote tracking one, and finally merge `tmp` to that resetted branches: a massive merge is quicker than thousands of patches to apply.